# How to ensure the Gaussian process output is always lower than one of the input variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I'm using the Gaussian process model to develop the relationship between three input variables (x1, x2, x3) and one output y. According to the realistic system, it is known that y should be always no larger than x1. How can I realize this constraint in developing Gaussian process models?